# Scheduler within Jboss Cluster- method get calles twice

Tags: spring, jboss

We are using: JBoss AS 7.1.1, Spring 3.1.0, Hibernate,..

We have following:

applicationContext.xml snippet:

```
    <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" />
    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10" />
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"
            scheduler="taskScheduler" />
```

method:

```
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
    ...
      @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 * *")
    public void reportMonthly() {
      // do database stuff.
    }
```

Our problem is that our web application runs in a cluster (2-4 nodes) and every node calls this method. How we can avoid that?

Or its more like a bug in spring?

Answer (score 1):

How should Spring know you're running in a cluster? No, that's not a bug with Spring.

What's you're desired behavior anyway? Do you want to have your scheduler run on one node only? Or on all but a single task should only be executed once?

If it's the first then you need to disable the scheduler (or the individual tasks) through some means of configuration on all but one node.

We prefer to run the scheduler on each node for fail-safety reasons. We use the (single) database to synchronize the tasks. You need some clever locking mechanism but essentially before a task runs it queries the database to find out if one of its siblings is already running. If not, it writes the status 'running' to the database and clears this once it's done.